# Disabling Mouse Acceleration in VMware Player 17

Tags: windows, mouse, vmware, mouse-acceleration

Recently I have been using VMware, and it is a lot faster than VirtualBox, even with the same specs as a VirtualBox VM. However, I cannot find a way to disable mouse acceleration on VMware, but I have tried multiple methods, disabled Enhance Pointer Precision in the Control Panel, but nothing works. My main goal of this is to play Minecraft in a VM, but Mouse Acceleration makes the mouse have a mind of its own.

Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: Have you been making your changes on the host or the guest?

Comment: guest virtual machine

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

(1) Adjust mouse movement and acceleration in the host and that should pass through to the guest.

(2) Get a USB mouse, enable USB pass through to the guest machine, then set up the mouse as you need in the guest machine.

I have experimented with variations of this but not Minecraft.